# Images in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given $f(z)=2iz^{5/2}=2ie^{5/2Log(z)}$ and $A=\{z:|z|\leq4, 0\leq y \leq x\}$ and I have to find the image of A under f.

I have no idea how to do this. I've never really understood images. I know A is this eighth of a circle, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Try to describe $A$ using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $A$ has a boundary, consisting of (i) the segment from $z=0$ to $z=1$, (ii) the eighth of a circle, and (iii) the segment from $z=0$ to $z=e^{i\pi/4}$.  If you map each piece of the boundary by the transformation $f$, then the interior should map to the interior, and you are done.

Should be straightforward to map each of (i) and (ii).

You can parameterize (iii) by $z=re^{i\pi/4}$ with $0\le r \le 1$.

This maps to $2 i (re^{i\pi/4})^{5/2} = 2 i r^{5/2} e^{i5\pi/8}=2 r^{5/2} e^{i\pi/2}e^{5i\pi/8} = 2 r^{5/2}e^{9i\pi/8} = -2 r^{5/2}e^{i\pi/8}.$

Comment: So the parameterization for (i) is $z=r$ with $0 \leq r \leq 1$, right? But then what's the parameterization for (ii)?

Comment: Yes.  That's right!

Comment: For (ii), $z=r_0 e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ ranging from $0$ to $\pi/4$.

Comment: A small correction.  Somehow, I thought $r_0=1,$ but $r_0=4$, right!  So we'll have to adjust it ...

Comment: Just multiply everything by 4, please.  (i) the segment from $z=0$ to $z=4$, (ii) the eighth of a circle is $z=4e^{i\theta}$, and (iii) $z=re^{i\pi/4}$ with $0 \le r \le 4$.  The result for (iii) needs to be multiplied by $32=4^{5/2}$.  You see why?

Comment: Yes! That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!